# SSIS 2008 - Script Component - Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper - doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm trying to use a script component in an SSIS 2008 data flow.  I picked VB as the scripting language.  When I go to edit the script I see that 2 of the imports are erroring out.  Both the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper and Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper imports are throwing the following errors:

> Namespace or type specified in the Imports
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper' doesn't contain any public
>   member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is
>   defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the
>   imported element name doesn't use any aliases.
>
> Namespace or type specified in the Imports
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper' doesn't contain any public
>   member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is
>   defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the
>   imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check if all the refernces are there

[image]

use namespaces like this :

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

using PipeLineWrapper = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;

using RuntimeWrapper = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;